# Youtube Events work perfectly locally but only half on production

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I need to detect when a video gets to the end so I can close the shown video and bring the user back to the homepage. The strange thing is my player seems to fire events correctly only at the beginning of the video, after that, it stops firing events.

Here's a comparison between the local behavior and the live one:
[image]

On the left, you can see me starting the video and then pausing / playing a couple of times. On the right, you can see me doing the same thing, but only the first to events get registered.

Here's my code:

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: finalVideoId,
        playerVars: {
            showinfo: 0 ,
            wmode: "opaque",
            rel: 0,
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    setPlayerSize();
}

function setPlayerSize() {
    player.setSize($(document).width(), $(document).height() + 30)
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.data == 0) {
        alert('stop');
        mainMenuController.stopVideo();
    }

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
        if ($(window).width() < 1023) {
            mainMenuController.stopVideo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure the cache is empty and on live is exactly the same code, I checked.